# javascript for salutation in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm building a jquery mobile site and found a fabulous piece of javascript on here to post the form and redirect the site back to home page. The problem I have is it doesn't show the salutation in the sent email even though it's in the form and shows on the site as a drop down list starting with and showing 'MR'  when down arrow is clicked on the 'Mr' button. Below is the javascript and form. Any help will be gratefully received.

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setReqObj() {
    var nAjax;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    nAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    nAjax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   return nAjax;
}

function _SubmitForm() {
  var xmlhttp = setReqObj();

  if(xmlhttp) {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        document.forms["contact-form"].reset();

        $responseText = xmlhttp.responseText;
        alert("Your query has been successfully submitted!");
        document.location.href = "#home";
  }
  }



    var $validEmail = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;  
    var $name = document.forms["contact-form"]["Full_Name"].value;
    var $comments = encodeURIComponent(document.forms["contact-form"]["Query"].value);
    var $name2 = document.forms["contact-form"]["Phone"].value;
    var $email = document.forms["contact-form"]["Email"].value;


 if($name == "") {
      alert("Please enter a valid name!");
      return false;
    }

    if($comments.length <= 4) {
      alert("Please enter a valid comment!");
      return false;
    }
    if($name2 == "") {
      alert("Please enter a valid phone number!");
      return false;
    }
    if(!$email.match($validEmail)) {
      alert("Please enter a valid email address!");
      return false;
   }

    var $ajData = "Full_Name=" + $name + "&Query=" + $comments + "&Phone=" + $name2 + "&Email=" + $email;

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.test.uk.com/cgi-bin/cgiemail/emailform2.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send($ajData);
  } else {
    document.forms["contact-form"].submit();
  }
}
</script>
```

FORM

```
<fieldset data-role="ui-field-contain">  
  <div class="controlgroup">
  <legend>Enquiry Form</legend><br>
    <select name="salutation" id="salutation" >
      <option value="Mr">Mr</option> 
      <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
      <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
      <option  value="Miss">Miss</option>
    </select> 



    <br>
    <label for="fullname">Full name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Full_Name" id="fullname" />  

    <label for="query">Query:</label>
    <textarea name="Query" id="query"></textarea>

    <label for="phone">Phone Numbers:</label>
    <textarea name="Phone" id="phone" ></textarea>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email" id="email" />  
    </div>
  </fieldset>
```

-->

```
  </form>
```

Many thanks,
Ruwak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not picking the value of salutation from your form, and I think that's why you are not getting it in your email. First, pick the value for salutation:

```
var $salutation = document.forms["contact-form"]["salutation"].value;
```

Now, add this value to the data you are sending through ajax:

```
var $ajData = "Salutation=" + $salutation + "&Full_Name=" + $name + "&Query=" + $comments + "&Phone=" + $name2 + "&Email=" + $email;
```

Now, you should be getting the value of `Salutation` on your server. Still you need to make sure that on server side also, you are appending this value in the email that is sent.

Comment: Hi, Thanks to both of you for your replies, unfortunately none of them worked. It could be that I am placing them in the wrong place, I put them above the other var code for the rest of the email i.e. name, email etc but to no avail. I changed the <select> name to Salutation with a capital S, don't know if this has made a difference. – Ruak

Comment: Below is the query2 text on the server: To: enquiries@test.uk.com Subject: query2 Salutation? [Salutation][Mr][Mrs][Ms][Miss] Full Name? [Full_Name] Query? [Query] Phone Numbers? [Phone] E-mail? [Email] – Ruak

Comment: Sorry! Finally got it to work, it was me, when I added the 'var $ajData' line I forgot to delete the original.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't sending the selected salutation value with the request.  You need to capture the value then append it to the rest of your request:

`var $salutation = document.forms["contact-form"]["salutation"].value;`

Then depending on the server side code, either include it with the name:

`var $ajData = "Full_Name=" + $salutation + " " + $name + "&Query=" + $comments + "&Phone=" + $name2 + "&Email=" + $email;`

or include it as a seperate query string parameter:

`var $ajData = "Full_Name=" + $name + "&Query=" + $comments + "&Phone=" + $name2 + "&Email=" + $email + "&Salutation=" + $salutation;`

Comment: Hi,

Thanks to both of you for your replies, unfortunately none of them worked. It could be that I am placing them in the wrong place, I put them above the other var code for the rest of the email i.e. name, email etc but to no avail. I changed the <select> name to Salutation with a capital S, don't know if this has made a difference.

Comment: Below is the query2 text on the server:

To: enquiries@test.uk.com

Subject: query2

Salutation?               [Salutation][Mr][Mrs][Ms][Miss]
Full Name?               [Full_Name]
Query?                     [Query] 
Phone Numbers?     [Phone]
E-mail?                     [Email]

Comment: Sorry! Finally got it to work, it was me, when I added the 'var $ajData' line I forgot to delete the original.